# where should I post questions about profiling Adverts

Tags: discussion

I will post my question below, hopefully someone can direct me to the best stack exchange site to post it to.

I work for a large web site. We frequently receive reports about page performance degrading, and we often identify this as a "bad" advert, i.e. one that consumes too many browser resources.

What I am looking for is recommendations of how we can be more proactive about this. Right now we are only able to remove offending ads if someone reports it.

Ideally I would like a third party to monitor our site and email us when an ad starts playing up.

I would welcome recommendations for JavaScript we can place on our page to detect bad ads as well.

Comment: I don't think this will fly on SO.

Comment: If you want a tool or service, probably nowhere on the SE network (and definitely not on SO). If you can identify common features about bad adverts then you might be able to write an on-topic question asking how to write JavaScript to detect those features.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This kind of question will be closed as off topic because you're asking us to recommend you a tool. I cite the exact off-topic reason agreed on the site:

> Questions asking us to **recommend or find a book, tool, software library, tutorial or other off-site resource** are off-topic for Stack Overflow as they tend to attract opinionated answers and spam. Instead, describe the problem and what has been done so far to solve it.

It will be better if you change your question about asking something more specific and related to programming. For example, you may ask about you using a tool X and if you can *foo* with that tool after having done some research and you're sure the tool may *foo*. Note that we don't provide specific support for a tool but instead some user in SO that had used this tool may help you.

If you're thinking in posting this question somewhere else in stackexchange network due to the same reason.